# How to assign a numerical value to a user string input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a school assignment, where it requests a number of user inputs determining whether the user wants milk, juice, its size  For example, milk costs $4.00, upgrading to large costs $0.40,. At the end, the output should read for ex.

Large Milk,cost: $4.55

My issue is, how do I assign a value to each corresponding string input? At the end of the following code, the cost just spits out for sum of strings, as opposed to actually adding up the cost of each and spitting out the total number value. I just can't seem to figure out what I should be doing here.

Comment: Help us help you, and share the code you have so far.

Comment: Cut the problem down into individual steps then get googling and coding. Your computer won't explode if you make a mistake. I can understand it's daunting but you really won't learn without screwing up 99% of the time in the beginning. Knowing why 10 approaches to a problem don't work will teach you more than being given the one approach that does.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking if you want real help. Please post your code.

Comment: You can probably use a `dict` for this. It's hard to give more specific advice without seeing your code.

Comment: @Mureinik@PM2Ring@AlanGarrido I've since added my code

Answer (score 2):

In your final line to compute cost:

```
subtotal=(askSize + askBeverage + askFlav)
```

You do not sum the variables you defined at the top of your file (with costs), but you concatenate the strings that the user typed instead. For instance `askSize` can be the string "small". So, what you do here could be written as:

```
subtotal=("small" + "tee" + "lemon")
```

In Python, using `+` between strings will concatenate them. It means it will add the strings one after another to make a larger one. Example: `"foo" + "bar" = "foobar"`.

If you want to refer to the cost of each option, one solution (but there are other ones) would be to use a dictionary to store costs instead of several variables as you did:

```
# Dictionary of costs
costs = {"tea": 1.50,
         "coffee": 1.50,
         "small": 0,
         "medium": 0.75,
         "large": 1.75,
         "mint": 0.50,
         "lemon": 0.25,
         "chocolate": 0.75,
         "vanilla": 0.25,
         "none": 0
         }
```

Then, to get the number corresponding to a string, you get items from the dictionary:

```
tea_cost = costs["tea"]  # tea_cost will be equal to 1.50
ask_size_cost = costs[askSize]  # ask_size_cost will be equal to the cost of the asked size
```

Now, it is easy to get your total cost:

```
total_cost = costs[askSize] + costs[askBeverage] + costs[askFlav]
```

Of course, take care of string cases, everything must be lowercase in my example.

Hope it helps !

NB: You can do many improvements to the rest of your code, do not hesitate to read some Python code on the internet to get it better.

Comment: Good advice, but the price calculation code will only work if the user inputs exactly match the dictionary keys.

Comment: I think "tee" is a typo, in reference to the comment from PM 2Ring above. But, for the purposes of this exercise, I think the approach is sufficient to illustrate the way forward. You could call `.lower()` on the user input to get a better hit-rate, and use `costs.get()` which will return `None` if the key isn't found to make it more robust

Answer (score 0):

You need a `subtotal` variable you never declared, and then after every option selection you want to `+=` increment it:

```
subtotal = 0

askName = str(input("What is your name?")).title()
askBeverage = str(input("What type of beverage would you like?")).title()

if askBeverage.lower() in ("t", "tea"): #ensures any variation of upper/lowercase will work

    subtotal += 1.50

    askSize = str(input("Would you like a small, medium, or large Tea?")).title() # SIZE

    if askSize.lower() in ("small", "s"):
        subtotal += 0
    elif askSize.lower() in ('medium', 'm'):
        subtotal += .75
    elif askSize.lower() in ('large', 'l'):
        subtotal += 1.75
    else:
        print("Invalid size specified.")
        sys.exit()

    askFlav =str(input("Any flavourings for your Tea? Your options are mint, lemon, or none")).title() # FLAVOURING

    if askFlav.lower() in ("m", "mint"):
        subtotal += .50
    elif askFlav.lower() in ("l", "lemon"):
        subtotal += .25
    elif askFlav.lower() in ('none', 'n'):
        subtotal += 0
    else:
        print("Invalid flavour specified.")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Map `askSize.lower()[0]` in a dictionary to values

Comment: @roganjosh you want me to implement dictionaries, to someone struggling to keep a running subtotal after options are selected O.o

Comment: @roganjosh he stated its school work and I'm judging by the assignment if he popped up to his teacher with a dictionary sorting item prizes and sizes that would raise a few concerns

Comment: Fair enough, I'll let you off :)

Answer (score -1):

Your askSize, askBeverage, askFlav are strings, so you cannot add them without turning into numbers. Most straight forward solution is to change them into float.

`subtotal=float(askSize) + float(askBeverage) + float(askFlav)
print("For {}, a {} {}, with {:.2f} flavoring, cost: {}".format(askName,askSize,askBeverage,askFlav, subtotal))`

It seems you just started learning programming. Python is a good language to start. Please enjoy!